# Не выводит всплывающее окно после отправки формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, form

Здравствуйте, такая проблема. Есть форма, после отправки которой  и получению ответа от сервера, должно всплывать окно. форма работает, но окна нет, в чем может быть причина?

```
... 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buton" id="buton">
</form>
<div class="overlay js-overlay-thank-you">
    <div class="popup js-thank-you">
        <h2>Спасибо за заявку. Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время!</h2>
        <div class="close-popup js-close-thank-you"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Стили для всплывающего окна

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: none;
}

.popup{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.close-popup{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close-popup:before {
    content: " ";
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: -4px;
    width: 31px;
    height: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.close-popup:after {
    content: " ";
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: -4px;
    width: 31px;
    height: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

И скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(document.getElementById('form').name.value == '' || document.getElementById('form').email.value == '' || document.getElementById('form').phone.value == ''){
        valid = false;
        return valid;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $(".overlay").fadeIn();
            $(this).find("input").val('');
            $("#form").trigger("reset");
            },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(exception);
        }
    });
    return;
});
});
//закрыть форму
$(".close-popup").click(function() { 
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e) { 
    var popup = $(".popup");
    if (e.target!=popup[0]&&popup.has(e.target).length === 0){
        $(".overlay").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Точно всплывающее окно должно появиться `по отправлению`, а не `по получению ответа сервера`?

Comment: По получению ответа - конечно, простите, не так высказался)

Comment: @ЮрийГалай, все работает, окно всплывает: http://jsbin.com/nuwazemiqe/edit?js,output  (я только чуток отформатировал код, ничего особо не менял). Проверяйте скрипт `mail.php` - вероятно, он не возвращает ответ.

Comment: "форма работает" - ?? `$(this).find("input").val('');` - что здесь `this`?

Comment: @Igor Да, форма работает, но нету всплывающего окна. Вы можете мне помочь с этим, мои навыки минимальны, сам не справлюсь

Comment: @ЮрийГалай Могу. Давайте разбираться. 1. Выясним какой callback обработчик выполняется - success или error. Вставьте в них первой строчкой `console.log("success");` и `console.log("error");` соответственно.

Comment: @Igor Видимо мои навыки ниже минимальных... Можно конкретнее? Если вас не затруднит, конечно.

Comment: @yar85, Что конкретно должен возвращать php?
return success?

Comment: @ЮрийГалай, PHP-скрипт должен возвращать ответ с HTTP-кодом 200... это как минимум.

Comment: @yar85 Как это сделать?

Comment: @ЮрийГалай, _Как это сделать_ - это шутка? Если нет, то `http_response_code(200);` или `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так. Это не ответ.

Добавьте в код строчки, как показано ниже.

Нажмите в браузере F12. Откроется окно "Инструменты Разработчика". Там есть закладка "Console/Консоль". Запустите код. Какие сообщения появились в консоли?

```
console.log("sending ajax"); // добавить

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        console.log("success"); // добавить

        $(".overlay").fadeIn();
        $(this).find("input").val('');
        $("#form").trigger("reset");
        },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        console.log("error"); // добавить

        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(exception);
    }
});
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Если через Denwer, то таких ошибок 2, а через тестовый хостинг, то таких ошибок 13

Comment: sending ajax success;
Но я изменил скрипт.

Comment: но теперь на почту ничего не приходит